# How to handle Checkbox Checked/Unchecked event with Command in ViewModel in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a view (*X.Xaml*) which has some controls, including a `CheckBox`.

When I check the `CheckBox` it should make a session *True* and when I uncheck it, it has to make the session *False*.

If I do it in the `X.Xaml.cs` code-behind, it would be easy but I want my code to be clean.

Is there anyway to use Command and handle it in *ViewModel* side?

Comment: Must it be a Command? You can have a boolean property in your ViewModel and bind IsChecked from the CheckBox to it

Comment: I agree with Daniel.  It seems cleaner to me to use a binding. Unless there is other logic that needs to occur when this change is triggered from the Checkbox

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your question: yes, there is.

You have to create `Command` class implementing `ICommand`:

```
public class MyCommand : ICommand
{
    Action<bool> _action;
    public MyCommand(Action<bool> action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event System.EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _action((bool)parameter);
    }
}
```

then in your ViewModel create the command itself:

```
private MyCommand simpleCommand;
public MyCommand SimpleCommand
{
    get { return simpleCommand; }
    set { simpleCommand = value; }
}

public MainViewModel()
{
    SimpleCommand = new MyCommand(new Action<bool>(DoSomething));
}

public void DoSomething(bool isChecked)
{
    //something
}
```

And bind your `Checkbox` command to it, and the `CommandParameter` to `Checkbox.IsChecked`

```
<CheckBox Name="checkBox1" Command="{Binding Path=SimpleCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=checkBox1, Path=IsChecked}" />
```

But that's a bit exaggerated. You're probably better off creating respective `bool` property in the ViewModel, bind to it and invoke required code within the accessor.

Comment: You can use `RelayCommand<bool>` instead of your custom `MyCommand`.

Answer (score 6):

Why can't you simply create a TwoWay-Binding on the IsChecked-Property to a ViewModel-Property and react on that property change?

in the viewModel:

```
private bool _IsSessionEnabled;
public bool IsSessionEnabled
{
    get { return _IsSessionEnabled; }
    set {
        if (_IsSessionEnabled != value) {
            _IsSessionEnabled = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
            this.switchSession(value); /* this is your session code */
        }
    }
}
```

and in the view:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked={Binding IsSessionEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}
          Content="Session active" />
```

It would be even cleaner to respond on the Property Change in your own OnPropertyChanged implementation before (or after, as you like) raising the event.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a command, or you could use data binding with change notification.
In the view just bind to the command property of the checkbox.  I am just calling the command Changed.

```
Command={Binding Changed}"
```

ViewModel

```
bool session = false;
RelayCommand Changed = new RelayCommand(()=>{this.session = !this.session});
```

Comment: Relay command is is part of the MVVM light toolkit.  You can create your own command implementation but RelayCommand is so simple and versatile